# Kendo-UI Scheduler 'GetTimezoneOffset' Error

Tags: javascript, json, salesforce, crud, kendo-scheduler

To begin using Kendo UI to work on a calendar, I first am starting by pulling events from Salesforce org and just displaying them on the schedule. However, I am being plagued by "Cannot read property 'getTimezoneOffset' of undefined errors and am looking for help. My JS is:

```
var data = '{!jsonString}';
       var scheduler = $('#scheduler').kendoScheduler({
       date: new Date(),
       startTime: new Date(),
       height: 700,
       timezone: "Etc/UTC",
       views: [
          {type: "week", selected: true},
          "week",
          "month",
          "agenda"
       ],
       dataSource: {
          batch: true,
          transport: {
              read: function(e){
                  console.log(data);
                  e.success(data);
              },
              update: {
                  url: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/tasks/update",
                  dataType: "jsonp"
              },
              create: {
                  url: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/tasks/create",
                  dataType: "jsonp"
              },
              destroy: {
                  url: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/tasks/destroy",
                  dataType: "jsonp"
              },
              parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
                  if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                      return {models: kendo.stringify(options.models)};
                  }
              }
          },
          schema: {
              model: {
                  id: "OwnerId",
                  fields: {
                       taskId: { from: "TaskID" },
                       title: { from: "Title", defaultValue: "No title", validation: { required: true } },
                       start: { type: "date", from: "Start" },
                       end: { type: "date", from: "EndTime" },
                       startTimezone: { from: "StartTimezone" },
                       endTimezone: { from: "EndTimezone" },
                       description: { from: "Description" },
                       recurrenceId: { from: "RecurrenceID" },
                       recurrenceRule: { from: "RecurrenceRule" },
                       recurrenceException: { from: "RecurrenceException" },
                       ownerId: { from: "OwnerID", defaultValue: 1 },
                       isAllDay: { type: "boolean", from: "IsAllDay" }
                  }
              }
          }
      }
                        //});
  });
```

And the data variable is JSON in the format:

> [{"Title":"meeting","TaskId":"00U410000059ZjbEAE","StartTimezone":"Etc/UTC","Start":"2017-01-26",
>   "RecurrenceRule":null, "RecurrenceId":null,
>   "RecurrenceException":null, "OwnerId":"005410000020eLnAAI",
>   "IsAllDay":false, "EndTimezone":"Etc/UTC", "End":"2017-01-26",
>   "Description":"a meeting"},{"Title":"meeting",
>   "TaskId":"00U410000059ZjcEAE", "StartTimezone":"Etc/UTC",
>   "Start":"2017-01-26", "RecurrenceRule":null, "RecurrenceId":null,
>   "RecurrenceException":null, "OwnerId":"005410000020eU9AAI",
>   "IsAllDay":false, "EndTimezone":"Etc/UTC", "End":"2017-01-26",
>   "Description":"a meeting"}, etc...}]

According to the console.log(data) in the read operation. I have a controller that gets an array of events, then JSON.serializes that array (which is JSON String, which data accesses).

I don't get what the issue with the timezone offset is, all my JSON entry data matches the fields of the tutorial schema and it still doesn't work... I just need the calendar to display all events that currently exist when it is opened by passing this JSON to the read operation. Any help would be incredibly appreciated! Thank you.

Here is my controller:

```
global with sharing class CalendarData {

public List<Event> eventList{get;set;}
public String jsonString{get;set;}
public List<schedulerItem> correctedItems{get;set;}

public CalendarData(){
    String eventQuery = 'SELECT ActivityDate,ActivityDateTime,CreatedById,Description,DurationInMinutes,EventSubtype,IsAllDayEvent,Location,OwnerId,EndDateTime,StartDateTime,Subject FROM Event';
    eventList = Database.query(eventQuery);
    correctedItems = itemList(eventList);
    system.debug(correctedItems);
    jsonString = JSON.serialize(correctedItems);
    jsonString = jsonString.replace('"EndTime"', '"End"');
}

public List<schedulerItem> itemList(List<Event> events){
        Integer i = 0;
        system.debug(events);
        List<schedulerItem> kendoEvents = new List<schedulerItem>();
        schedulerItem item = new schedulerItem();
        for(i = 0; i < events.size(); i++){
            item.Description = events[i].Description;
            Datetime dt = events[i].EndDateTime;
            item.EndTime = dt.date();
            dt = events[i].StartDateTime;
            item.Start = dt.date();
            item.EndTimezone = 'Etc/UTC';
    //public String id;
            item.IsAllDay = events[i].IsAllDayEvent;
            item.RecurrenceException = null; 
            item.RecurrenceId = null;
            item.RecurrenceRule = null;
            item.StartTimezone = 'Etc/UTC';
            item.Title = events[i].Subject;
            item.TaskId = events[i].Id;
            item.OwnerId = events[i].OwnerId;
            system.debug(item);
            kendoEvents.add(item);

            item = new schedulerItem();
        }
        return kendoEvents;
    }

public class schedulerItem{
    public String Description;
    public Date EndTime;
    public Date Start;
    public String EndTimezone;
    //public String id;
    public Boolean IsAllDay;
    public String RecurrenceException; 
    public String RecurrenceId;
    public String RecurrenceRule;
    public String StartTimezone;
    public String Title;
    public String TaskId;
    public String OwnerId;

}
}
```

I get a list of events, then use a custom class to create a new list to bind data from the original events list to events with data names that match the schema model names from the tutorial. I also replace all "EndTime" with "End."

Found a solution to read my events:

```
var data = '{!jsonString}';
                var dataList = JSON.parse(data);
                function getNewEvents() {
                    var eventList = [];
                    for(var i = 0; i < dataList.length; i++){
                        //console.log("DataList Again: " + dataList[i]);
                        var kendoEvent = new kendo.data.SchedulerEvent({
                            id: i,
                            taskId: dataList[i].TaskId,
                            title: dataList[i].Title,
                            start: new Date(dataList[i].Start),
                            end: new Date(dataList[i].End),
                            startTimezone: dataList[i].StartTimezone,
                            endTimezone: dataList[i].EndTimezone,
                            description: dataList[i].Description,
                            recurrenceId: dataList[i].RecurrenceId,
                            recurrenceRule: dataList[i].RecurrenceRule,
                            recurrenceException: dataList[i].RecurrenceException,
                            ownerId: dataList[i].OwnerId,
                            isAllDay: dataList[i].IsAllDay
                        });
                        eventList.push(kendoEvent);
                    }
                    return eventList;
                }
                eventData = getNewEvents();
```

I took my returned JSON array, then parsed it back to just an array of objects, then created a new array of actual kendo.data.SchedulerEvents and filled in all fields with correct names. Then in my read operation in the data source, instead of the URL and datatype, I did:

```
read: function(e){
    e.success(data);
}
```

Where data is my array of kendo scheduler events. Now, my schedule shows all the events in my org. Now I will need to work on the update, destroy, and create operations :). The links provided in the comments of the accepted answer helped me reach this solution with necessary documentation.

Comment: the most common reason for the "getTimezoneOffset of null" error is incorrectly passed/set date values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be other reason for this issue as i mentioned in comment but looking into the code one of the error is **incorrect configuration of model as well incorrect read configuration**

There is no incoming field in JSON as  **EndTime** instead it is **End**.

Change the **EndTime** to **End** match the declaration of field with incoming JSON

```
{"Title":"meeting","IsAllDay":false,"EndTimezone":"Etc/UTC","End":"2017-01-26", "Description":"a meeting"}
```

Here is the Fields declaration

```
    fields: {
                           taskId: { from: "TaskID" },
                           title: { from: "Title", defaultValue: "No title", validation: { required: true } },
                           start: { type: "date", from: "Start" },
 // problem was here there is no EndTime as mentioned in the given code sample above .
// changed to End as it is in the incoming JSON
                           end: { type: "date", from: "End" },
                           startTimezone: { from: "StartTimezone" },
                           endTimezone: { from: "EndTimezone" },
                           description: { from: "Description" },
                           recurrenceId: { from: "RecurrenceID" },
                           recurrenceRule: { from: "RecurrenceRule" },
                           recurrenceException: { from: "RecurrenceException" },
                           ownerId: { from: "OwnerID", defaultValue: 1 },
                           isAllDay: { type: "boolean", from: "IsAllDay" }
                      }
```

For more details refer to this basic example on telerik website.

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scheduler/index

**Correct Read Configuration**

Please use this read I am not sure if your controller is return correct data and your binding is not correct

```
read: { url: "demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/tasks";, dataType: "jsonp" }
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! But I changed EndTime to just End and still get the error. Is my read operation correct? Is that how you successfully populate a scheduler with a local json array? I can't figure out what is wrong :(

Comment: read: {
                    url: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/tasks",
                    dataType: "jsonp"
                }

Comment: I added my controller. Also, I originally got it to work with the test read that you just posted. However, that pulls their pre-set events. So after I got those, I wanted to change the read operation to populate the schedule with local data (my retrieved json array of events from a salesforce org).

Comment: Ok, no problem. Will do. I really appreciate your help. I attempted to up-vote, but it says it is recorded but doesn't appear publicly for me :(

Comment: I was possibly wondering if it is because when I serialize the array to json, it gets surrounded with '  '  single quotes, and maybe it can't have those when passed to read? But de-serializing it just reverts it back to the original array instead of json array.

Comment: not sure if you are using .net as a backend while i am looking into your issue please read the basics of kendo scheduler at http://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/helpers/scheduler/ajax-editing

Comment: I am using Apex programming for my controller.

Comment: the json data you are binding to not correct as well as the configuration to bind to local data is also not correct. you need to spend time on reading some documentation and do some research  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285506/unable-to-populate-kendo-scheduler-with-data
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27228036/unable-to-bind-data-to-kendo-scheduler

Comment: I have been looking for information to research binding my data to the scheduler and creating a correct Read operation, but have not found a ton that is very helpful. What about my json data is not correct? It has all the fields that are named exactly the same as the demo on the scheduler demo site, they just are not in the same order, does order matter? And thank you for the links to those questions. They may prove helpful, but not sure the syntax and code interactions will be the same as I am using Javascript and Apex controllers.

Comment: json data is not correct open this link in your browser this is what you were getting back when you use test code and it work .  this link has struture of json data https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/tasks

Comment: the order does not matter , the configuration to read data from local using scheduler is different look into this it helped me so many times . go through whole page and read the concept properly http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/schedulerdatasource

Comment: Hmmm my data should be correct except the dates. The issue is i get dates back in yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss format from my database, and they have dates as \/Date(1370811600000)\/ kind of format, which I assume is... milliseconds? Is that specific format necessary? I suppose I would have to attempt to convert the date I get into ms to put in the json array if that is possible.

Comment: And thank you for the link. I don't think I found that information as of yet.

Comment: I found out how to read in my events from my salesforce org instead of just kendo's demo events! I posted how I fixed it in my original question. Your links helped lead me to this solution :). Thank you for your time and effort in solving this, this held me up for a couple days!

Comment: Sure, if you'd like my information about my solution on your blog :)